# Order By not working on joined and grouped MySQL tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql

**What I'm trying to achieve:** I'm trying to build a private messaging script. The part of the script which has me confused is the displaying of messages between two users. I'd like to show the last message that has been sent between them

**My problem:** When I perform 3 joins within one PHP/MySQL query and then use GROUP BY and ORDER BY DESC I expect the last message of that conversation to be shown...but the first one appears instead.

**My code structure:** I have three MySQL tables; Users (holding user login information), Messages (holding the contents of any messages) and Conversations (holding information about who the conversation is between):

USERS table:

```
 user_id | user_name
 1       | Dave
 2       | Bill
 3       | Rob
```

CONVERSATIONS table:

```
 conversation_id | user_one_id | user_two_id
 1               | 1           | 2
```

MESSAGES table:

```
 message_id | conversation_id | sender_user_id | receiver_user_id | message
 1          | 1               | 1              | 2                | Hey how are you?
 2          | 1               | 2              | 1                | Not bad. You?
 3          | 1               | 1              | 2                | Okay
```

and I have the following MySQL query:

```
 SELECT u.user_name, c.conversation_id, m.sender_user_id, m.message
 FROM conversations c
 JOIN messages m ON c.conversation_id=m.conversation_id
 JOIN users u ON u.user_id=m.sender_id
 WHERE c.user_one_id=$user_id AND m.sender_user_id<>:$user_id
 GROUP BY u.user_name
 ORDER BY m.message_id DESC
```

**The output:** When I supply $user_id=2 and echo user_name and message is:

```
 Dave: Hey how are you?
```

as opposed to displaying the last record:

```
 Dave: okay
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using group by in absence of aggregation will result in indeterminate order it will not guarantee you the latest or earliest order you can use a self join to pick the latest message per converstion

```
SELECT u.user_name, c.conversation_id, m.sender_user_id, m.message
 FROM conversations c
 JOIN messages m ON c.conversation_id=m.conversation_id
 JOIN users u ON u.user_id=m.sender_user_id
JOIN (select max(message_id) message_id ,conversation_id
     from messages 
      group by conversation_id
     ) m1
ON(m.message_id= m1.message_id and m.conversation_id = m1.conversation_id)
 WHERE .....
 ORDER BY m.message_id DESC
```

[**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a79c5/7)